# Move the bottom of a curve without changing both ends

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having a curve as follows:

[image]

The curve is generated with the following code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# normalize array
def min_max_scale_array(arr):
    arr = np.array(arr)
    return (arr - arr.min())/(arr.max()-arr.min())

x = np.linspace(-50,48,100)
y = x**2 + 2*x + 2  

x = min_max_scale_array(x)
y = min_max_scale_array(y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
```

How can I generate a new curve by moving only the bottom left (or right) and keeping both ends the same like this? Thank you!

[image]

Edit: any curve generating algorithm is appreciated, as long as it works!

Comment: The problem you are having is a mathematical one. Quadratic curves will *always* be symmetrical. You seem to be looking for a 4th degree polynomial

Comment: What is `min_max_scale_column`? Is it a typo? I am afraid your code won't run if pasted into a console as-is.

Comment: @PabloGutierrezMarques there is a simpler solution, just generate a new set of `x` stretched/squeezed where necessary

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm looking for a way (algorithms, packages, ...) to achieve this, so anything would do

Comment: Maybe define why and how you want to transform the curve?

Comment: @matszwecja Yes both ends of the curve remains the same, only the bottom is changed, as for why I want to make many variations of a pattern for data augmentation in machine learning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing so is defining `x,y` as before, but applying a shift. The dotted line shows if you just shift it. But now at the top most `y` we don't want to shift it, so we'd like to weight the shifted version on the bottom (`y=0`) by `1` but on the top (`y=1`) by `0` such that we get a gradual interpolation. We can do this by multiplying the shift by `(1-y)`:

[image]

```
a = 0.25  # how far to shift left
plt.plot(x, y, 'k')
plt.plot(x-a, y, 'k:')
plt.plot(x-a*(1-y), y, 'r')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution: apply a sublinear transformation to x - a quadratic function will work.

```
x = x**2  # works because x is scaled to 0-1
ax.plot(x, y)
```

[image]

UPD: as requested, a scaling factor would look something like:

```
scaling_factor = 0.7
x = scaling_factor*(x**2) + (1-scaling_factor)*x
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! How about moving the bottom of the curve to the right?